# Background application vs service

Tags: android

I have an application that I wants it to keep running when user puts it in the background. I was wondering what would be the difference between an application put in the background (so `onPause()` is called) and a `Service`? They seem both to be working in the background

Thanks

Comment: There are 3 ways to create a background service. You can choose one: 1) `IntentService` 2) `Service` 3) `AsyncTask`. I recommend you to use `IntentService` because its thread will running in background and flexible for long-running thread than `Service`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running
>   operations in the background

When your Activity goes into onPause, there is no guarantee from the system that it will not be destroyed next. In your case, you aren't seeing it perhaps because you have enough memory available, but under different circumstances and on different phones, the Activity *can* be destroyed, even if you are doing work. Therefore you should use the service for background tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Service. Even though your Activity can continue to execute code after onPause() or onStop(), you should use a service. A Service is not meant to have a UI and the system prioritizes them differently when deciding to kill components that are no longer in use if the system needs to reclaim memory.